# getDownloadUrl returns null in android studio

Tags: java, android

I've been battling with this problem for a while now and I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong

```java
     ref.putFile(filePath).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imagesDatabaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child(getspinner() + "_images");
                    String imageKey = imagesDatabaseReference.push().getKey();
                    imagesDatabaseReference.child(imageKey).setValue(imageID);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: image uploaded");
                    task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                            downloadUrl = task.getResult().toString();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    downloadUrl = "unable to get download url";
                }
            }
        });
        return downloadUrl;
```

My code should upload an image, and return a url. It uploads perfectly, but does not return any download url (`downloadUrl` stays `null`). I think problems could be:

- permissions error (even if I can upload images)
- activity closes before the uploadlistener is compeleted

LogCat:

```
    2020-03-01 02:34:35.788 8109-8109/com.example.pineapplemark8 D/Constraints: oncomplete: getdownloadurl
2020-03-01 02:34:37.386 8109-8167/com.example.pineapplemark8 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8f66fc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe8f9a240)
2020-03-01 02:34:37.422 2340-2503/? W/InputDispatcher: channel 'e5bbb34 Toast (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
2020-03-01 02:34:37.422 2340-2503/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'e5bbb34 Toast (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2020-03-01 02:34:37.426 2340-4348/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'e5bbb34 Toast (server)'
2020-03-01 02:34:19.847 2340-2363/? E/RemoteAugmentedAutofillService: Bad service name for flags 1048704: com.google.android.as/com.google.android.apps.miphone.aiai.app.AiAiAugmentedAutofillService
2020-03-01 02:34:37.447 2340-4348/? W/NotificationService: Toast already killed. pkg=com.example.pineapplemark8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@7b159b8
2020-03-01 02:34:37.945 2685-4701/? W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is the `onComplete` function executed? Can you show us the LogCat content?

Comment: I added an Log.d line just above downloadurl = task.getresult.tostring and it did show up in logcat (as seen above)

Comment: I found that if I ran Log.d(TAG, task.getResult().toString(); it shows the right link in logCat, so the issue must be where I transfer the link to a variable.